# Path collision with certain fields in Mongo Compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema of authors and books and their addresses as:

```
const addr = {
  building: String,
  block: String,
  city: String,
  pin: Number
}

const authorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
books: [String],
address: addr
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema);
```

Now when I try to back up as JSON or CSV, I get error

```
Path collision at address.building remaining portion building
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is when you select All Fields while you take backup. You'll find the options selected in fields:

```
address <tick>                            // problem starts here
address.building <tick>
address.block <tick>
address.city <tick>
```

Unselect address or all address.`allFields` before taking backup and it'll work

An example from a previous project.
[image]

Comment: This works,
If only specific properties of field are required, make sure to unselect main field.
In my case I had selected `{ views: 1, views._id: 1 }` removing `view:1` solved the issue